# Override a file and truncate the non-overridden part

Tags: c++, file-io

How would I overwrite the contents of a file and truncate the parts of the file that were not overwritten using C++? Specifically, I use a temporary file to hold an edited copy of the original data and want to overwrite the original file with the new data, and truncate the rest of the original file.

For code in question: https://github.com/Sparen/DanmakufuObfuscator/blob/master/dnhobf_fxn.cc
(`RemoveSingleLineComments(FILE* infile)`)

For clarification, this is what I want to do:
Let's say the original is ABCDEFGHIJK. I want to remove B, D, H, and J, resulting in ACEFGIK. I copy this back, and end up with ACEFGIKHIJK. I want to remove that last HIJK

Comment: I don't have anything at all in regards to truncation, because I have yet to find a suitable method

Comment: If you have the new content in a temp file, why not delete the old one and rename the new one?

Comment: Let's say the original is ABCDEFGHIJK. I want to remove B, D, H, and J, resulting in ACEFGIK. I copy this back, and end up with ACEFGIKHIJK. I want to remove that last HIJK.

Comment: This still doesn´t explain why you´re copying the temp file back at all instead of using the temp file as new original one. And what does your second paragraph mean (`I require that...`)? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @deviantfan: As of right now, I don't know if there will be text encoding issues, though making the temp file the new one is possible. The second paragraph refers to me not knowing the file size of the files, and perhaps not being able to get the file size.

Comment: Why are you using FILE* instead of fstream?

Comment: @celticminstrel That's the way I learned it.

Comment: @celticminstrel: Is it possible to reopen a fstream under a different mode? If so, then that will solve my issue.

Comment: @AndrewFan So the real problem was/is that you´re not sure how many bytes were overwritten? With FILE*, ftell will help you.

Comment: @AndrewFan: Did you learn it before C++ was standardised in 1998? :)

Comment: I don't know of a C++ equivalent to freopen(), but there's nothing to prevent you calling close() followed by open().

Comment: @deviantfan: That's not really the only problem: I want to preserve all metadata and anything else stored in the files, whether it's text encoding or different languages.

Comment: @celticminstrel: Basically, close it after copying the data, and reopening it under trunc before pasting? I'll try that.

Comment: A file on operating systems like Linux and Windows has no charset and/or language metadata. ... Other than using the temp file as new file, I still think truncate could help you. There are just bytes in the file.

Comment: A file does have metadata on Linux (and probably Windows, and certainly Mac) systems, but I've never heard of charset or language being part of that.

Comment: @celticminstrel Yes, I was refering to charsets and language. I know that other metadata exist (a lot of it)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: We learned File IO in C and didn't do much with it in C++. I'm switching to fstreams and I'll see if that makes the truncation work.

Comment: @AndrewFan: Hmm, bit of a tip: don't take things you learnt in C and do them in C++. The compatibility is misleading: they are different languages and work best when you treat them as such!

Comment: @AndrewFan If switching, note that fstreams sadly don´t have something like the `truncate()` function.

Comment: @deviantfan: But you can wipe upon opening, I guess.

Anyways, it seems that `get()` never returns EOF. So I have to fix that...

Comment: @AndrewFan Yes, but you can´t specify how many bytes should be truncated. It´s "all or nothing".

Comment: All or nothing is fine... for now.

Anyways, since `get()` never returns EOF, I need to find another way to break the now-infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write to the same file as you read. Instead:

1. Open `file.txt` for reading.
2. Open `file.txt.new` for writing.
3. Read a line from `file.txt`, perform your map/filter operations, and write the result to `file.txt`.
4. Repeat step 3 until `EOF`.
5. Close the files.
6. Rename `file.txt.new` over `file.txt`.

The benefit over working in place is that you won't end up with garbage if your program crashes or you lose power. As a rule, I *only* open files either:

1. that do not exist yet
2. in append mode (for logs)

Comment: Thanks. I was doing a costly recopy instead of just renaming the file. Will take into mind.

Answer (score 0):

Open the original file as an fstream. Once the temporary file has everything it needs to, close the original file. Reopen the original file with out and trunc modes, and write back to it.

This allows you to basically paste the contents of the temporary file onto a blank slate with the same filename and extension.

Comment: Important warning: if you lose power or your program crashes, you will lose your file.